# Eliminate all duplicates according to a key + keep records from a table which are not in another table

Tags: r, data.table

Question 1:

I am relatively new to R and I have two distinct questions.
I need to eliminate duplicates according to a key (single or multiple) but all of them so `unique` wouldn't do it. I also found the function `duplicated` but it will mark as true only from the second occurrence onward, but I need to eliminate all of them.

```
> DT <- data.table(Key=c("a","a","a","b","c"),var=c(1:5))
> DT
   Key var
1:   a   1
2:   a   2
3:   a   3
4:   b   4
5:   c   5
> unique(DT)
   Key var
1:   a   1
2:   b   4
3:   c   5
> duplicated(DT)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

what I want instead is

```
   Key var
1:   b   4
2:   c   5
```

Question 2:

I have 2 data tables and I want to keep only records from `DTFrom` for which the combination of values from the 2 (or more keys) is not in `DTFilter` (I found similar questions for SQL but not r):

```
   > DTFrom
    key1 key2 var
 1:    q    m   1
 2:    q    n   2
 3:    q    b   3
 4:    w    n   4
 5:    e    m   5
 6:    e    n   6
 7:    e    b   7
 8:    r    n   8
 9:    r    b   9
10:    t    m  10
11:    t    n  11
12:    t    b  12
13:    t    v  13
> DTFilter
   key1 key2 var
1:    q    m   1
2:    w    n   4
3:    e    b   7
4:    e    n   6
5:    r    n   8
6:    r    b   9
7:    t    m  10
8:    t    v  13
```

and I want the result to be:

```
    > DTOut
   key1 key2 var
1:    q    n   2
2:    q    b   3
3:    e    m   5
4:    t    n  11
5:    t    b  12
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you can use the `fromLast` argument in `duplicated`:

```
DT[ !(duplicated(Key) | duplicated(Key, fromLast = TRUE))]
#   Key var
#1:   b   4
#2:   c   5
```

For the second question, you can do:

```
setkey(DTFrom, key1, key2)
DTFrom[!DTFilter]
#   key1 key2 var
#1:    e    m   5
#2:    q    b   3
#3:    q    n   2
#4:    t    b  12
#5:    t    n  11
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question you can use `table` function for additional filtering:

```
DT[!duplicated(Key)][table(DT$Key) == 1,]
#    Key var
# 1:   b   4
# 2:   c   5
```

As for the second question there is `anti_join` function in `dplyr` package specially for this case:

```
require("dplyr")
anti_join(DTFrom, DTFilter, by = c("key1", "key2"))
#   key1 key2 var
# 1    e    m   5
# 2    q    b   3
# 3    q    n   2
# 4    t    n  11
# 5    t    b  12
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method for the first question is:

```
DT[.(DT[ , .N, by=key(DT)][N==1L, !"N"])]
```

Similarly we can do:

```
DT[.(DT[, .N, by=key(DT)][N==1L, ]), .SD]
```

@docendodiscimus 's answer for Q2 is also mine.